# How to pass the path of my JSON using JStree? Can I use /create another treeview CRUD?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, jstree

I'm using Jstree and trying to put my JSON to the code using a method who I created that get the path to the JSON but I don't have any success. Have another way using just ASP.net core to create a CRUD viewtree without using Jstree? If don't have, how can I make it works?

The code:

```js
let data_2 = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model.texto2));
var teste = decodeURIComponent("@Html.Raw(Model.getFile())");
window.location = teste;

$(document).ready(function (){
//parte do ajax
//fim ajax
        
  var dataJson = JSON.parse(data_2);
  $('#html1').jstree(
    {
      "core": {
         "themes": {
             "variant": "large"
         },
         "max_children":2
    },
      "plugins": ["contextmenu", "dnd", "search",
         "state", "types", "wholerow"],
            "root": {
               "valid_children": ["default"]
            }
      }
  );
  $('#html2').jstree(
    {
      "core": {
         "themes": {
             "variant": "large"
         },
         "max_children":2
    },
       "plugins": ["contextmenu", "dnd", "search",
           "state", "types", "wholerow"],
       "json_data": {
          "ajax": {
             "url": "",
             "data": function (n) {
                return {
                  id: n.attr ? n.attr("id") : 0
                }
             }
          }
      }
  );
        
});
```

I tried to put my JSON (a simple JSON just to make it works firstly) into JStree to make a CRUD with the framework.

```json
{
  "root": {
    "branche": "example"
  }
}
```

Update: i finally solved my first problem! but now i have another problem:I need to transform that path (the get file()) into a URL path. How can i do it? The new edit:

```
 $('#html2').jstree //  "@Html.Raw(Model.getFile().Replace(@"\", "/"))", <-- the data
  (
    {
      "core": {
        "themes": {
            "variant": "large"
        },
        'data':{
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Html.Raw(Model.getFile().Replace(@"\", "/"))",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                data.d;
                $(data).each(function () {
                    return { "id": this.id };
                });
            }
        }
      }
        
    }
  );
```

Comment: I know that the code now is all of the place, but it was because i tried everything and become like this. Sorry for the inconvenient.